# Gradient not redrawing properly

Tags: swiftui

I am attempting to have a CGRect that has a dynamic gradient. When I use the view models gradient I am able to observe the gradient changing. However the view does not change as expected.

If I use hardcoded gradients in the view which toggle between red and blue I see that the view is redrawing with the updated gradient.

What am I missing?

View Model:

```
    @Published var forceRedraw: Bool = false
    @Published var annGradient: Gradient = Gradient(colors: [.red]) {
        didSet {
            print("ViewModel", annGradient.stops.first!, annGradient.stops.last!)
            forceRedraw.toggle()
        }
    }
```

View:

```
struct SchematicView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var vM: AppViewModel
    @State var refresh: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            
            Spacer()
            ScrollView {
                if refresh {
                    Canvas { context, size in
                        let w = size.width
                        let h = size.height
                        let grad = vM.annGradient
                        print("View1", grad.stops.first!, grad.stops.last!)

                        let annPath = CGRect(x: w/2, y: 0, width: 100, height: h)
                        
                        context.fill(Path(annPath), with: .linearGradient(grad, startPoint: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), endPoint: CGPoint(x: 0, y: h)))
                    }.frame(width: 300, height: 500)
                } else {
                    Canvas { context, size in
                        let w = size.width
                        let h = size.height
                        let grad = vM.annGradient
                        print("View2", grad.stops.first!, grad.stops.last!)

                        
                        let annPath = CGRect(x: w/2, y: 0, width: 100, height: h)
                        
                        context.fill(Path(annPath), with: .linearGradient(grad, startPoint: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), endPoint: CGPoint(x: 0, y: h)))
                    }.frame(width: 300, height: 500)
                }
                
            }
            .syncBool($vM.forceRedraw, with: $refresh)
            .onAppear(perform: {
                refresh = vM.forceRedraw
            })
```

Comment: when / how are you updating the gradient? What does `syncBool` do?

Comment: Both branches of your "if" do exactly the same thing, I'm not sure what you're going for there. If the gradient is a published var then updating it will cause your view to re-evaluate the body. I don't think you need all the extra stuff